# Como utilizar un Scope en laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy tratando de realizar un buscador en laravel

Este es mi modelo

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class Futbol extends Model
{
    protected $connection='mysql';
    protected $table="cards";

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 'posicion','edad'
    ];

    public function scopeSearch($query, $nombre){

        return $query->where('nombre','LIKE',"%$nombre%");
    }
}
```

Este es mi controlador

```html
public function futbolistas(Request $request){


    $cards=Futbol::Search($request->nombre) -> all();

return view('screens.futbolistas', compact('cards'));

}
```

Esta es la vista

```html
    <div class="row">
        @for($i=0; $i<count($cards); $i++)
        <div class=" p-5 col-3 pb-5 border-bottom">
            <div class="card" >
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{asset('img').'/'.$cards[$i]->nom_imagen}}" width="350">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">Nombre: <b>{{$cards[$i]->nombre}}</b></h6>
                <p class="card-text">Posición: {{$cards[$i]->posicion}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">Edad: {{$cards[$i]->edad}} años</p>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endfor
    </div>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar solamente las cards view que coincidan con el elemento buscado.
No se como implementar el evento Scope para que pueda funcionar
**¿Como puedo mostrar las cards view que busque en el imput?**

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con algo así:

```
$cards = Futbol::search($request->nombre)->get();
```

Y para recorrer cada Card usa mejor los "foreachs"

```
@foreach($cards as $card)
   <p>{{ $card->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Super muchas gracias!